# Counting card hand values in Java with aces being both High and Low

Tags: java

I have a Card Class which contains an enum for both suit and rank of the cards, although I've been told by my lecturers that the value of the ACE rank must be 11, but then in the hand class when I create and store the list of potential hand values I'm not sure how to do it.

For example if I had a hand of  <10 Diamonds, Ace Spades, Ace Clubs> it has total value of 12, 22 or 32.

And if I had a more complex hand with more cards and more aces then it makes it quite difficult for me to think of an algorithm I could use to store these values.

Here is the code for my Card class:

```
public class Card implements Comparable, Serializable{

    static final long serialVersionUID = 100;

    private final Rank rank;
    private final Suit suit;

    public static enum Suit{CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES}

    public static enum Rank{
        TWO(2), THREE(3), FOUR(4), FIVE(5), SIX(6),SEVEN(7), EIGHT(8),
        NINE(9), TEN(10), JACK(10), QUEEN(10), KING(10), ACE(11);
    final int cardValue;
    /**
     * Creating an array of the rank enums used
     * to get the next rank in the list
    */
    private final static Rank[] cardRanks = values();
    Rank(int x) {
        cardValue = x;
    }
    public int getValue(){return cardValue;}
    //Getting the next enum in the list
    public Rank getNext(){return cardRanks[(this.ordinal()+1)
            %cardRanks.length];}
    }

    public Card(Rank r, Suit s) {
        this.rank = r;
        this.suit = s;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object card) {
       
        if(this.getRank().getValue()==
                ((Card)card).getRank().getValue()) {
            //If there ranks are the same sort them in suit order
            return this.getSuit().ordinal()-
                    ((Card)card).getSuit().ordinal();
        }else
            /**
             * If the ranks are different sort 
             * them in ascending rank order
            **/
            return (this.getRank().getValue())
                    -(((Card)card).getRank().getValue()); 
        
    }

    public Rank getRank() {
        return this.rank;
    }
    public Suit getSuit() {
        return this.suit;
    }    

    public static int sum(Card a, Card b) {
        return (a.getRank().getValue()) + (b.getRank().getValue());
    }

    public static boolean isBlackjack(Card a, Card b) {       
        return sum(a, b) == 21;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = this.getRank().name()+ " of " 
                   + this.getSuit().name();
        return s;
    }

    public static class CompareDescending 
                    implements Comparator<Card> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Card o1, Card o2) {
        
            if(o1.getRank()==o2.getRank()) {
                //If there ranks are the same sort them in suit order
                return o1.getSuit().ordinal()-o2.getSuit().ordinal();
            }else
                //For decending order
                return (o2.getRank().getValue())-(o1.getRank().getValue());  
        }
    
    }   
    
    public static class CompareSuit 
                        implements Comparator<Card> {
    
        private final int highestCardValue = 11;
 
        @Override
        public int compare(Card o1, Card o2) {
        
            int cardOneValue = 
                    ((o1.getSuit().ordinal()*highestCardValue)
                     +o1.getRank().ordinal());
            int cardTwoValue = 
                    ((o2.getSuit().ordinal()*highestCardValue)
                     +o2.getRank().ordinal());
        
             return cardOneValue-cardTwoValue;
        }       
    }  
}
```

And below is my current Hand class

```
package programming2coursework;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;


public class Hand implements Iterable<Card> {

    private ArrayList<Card> hand; 
    private ArrayList<Integer> handValues = new ArrayList();
    private int numOfSpades = 0;
    private int numOfHearts = 0; 
    private int numOfDiamonds = 0;
    private int numOfClubs =0;

    public Hand() {
    
        hand  = new ArrayList();
    
    }

    public Hand(Card[] cards) {
    
        hand  = new ArrayList();
    
        for (Card card : cards) {
            hand.add(card);
        
            switch(card.getSuit()){
                case CLUBS:
                    numOfClubs++;
                    break;
                case DIAMONDS:
                    numOfDiamonds++;
                    break;
                case HEARTS:
                    numOfHearts++;
                    break;
                case SPADES:
                    numOfSpades++;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public Hand(Hand h) {
    
        hand  = new ArrayList();
            
        for (Card card : h.hand) {
            hand.add(card);
        
            switch(card.getSuit()){
                case CLUBS:
                    numOfClubs++;
                    break;
                case DIAMONDS:
                    numOfDiamonds++;
                    break;
                case HEARTS:
                    numOfHearts++;
                    break;
                case SPADES:
                    numOfSpades++;
                    break;
            }
        }
    } 

    public void handValues() {
    
        int numOfAces = 0;
        int handValue = 0;
       
        for (Card hand1 : hand) {
            if(hand1.getRank() == Card.Rank.ACE)
                numOfAces++;
        
            handValue =+ hand1.getRank().getValue();                       
        }
        //Store highest possible hand value
        handValues.add(handValue);
    
        while(numOfAces != 0) {
            //Work out hand values?
            numOfAces--;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Card> iterator() {
        Iterator defaultIterator = hand.iterator();
        return defaultIterator;
    } 
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: IIRC, in blackjack the value of a hand is better of worse the closer it gets to ?21? without overshooting. So, of all the possible values of a hand, you would only want to select one of them (which you can determine without additional data), is that right?

Comment: That is correct, but I've been asked to store every possible value of the hand. This part of my work is not to do with blackjack, but to do with a generic card class.

Comment: I know this is not what you want to hear, but I disagree with your lecturer. The ace cards do not have a single value, but rather two. The Rank enum should have a collection of values, rather than a single one. The getValue should return a collection {maybe rename to getValues()}. From there, you should modify your the rest of your design accordingly.

Comment: I 100% agree with you and I would make other design changes too if it were possible, but I get marked on following a specific design given to me by my lecturer. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate all counts:

- Count the *value* of non ace cards (`k`)
- Count the *number* of ace cards (`a`).

The value of Aces (`aValue`) ranges from `a` (all count as 1) to `11*a` (all count as 11)

```
 int aValue = a;
 while (aValue < 11*a) {
    handValues.add(k + aValue);
    aValue = aValue + 10; // an 1 becomes an 11,
 }
 handValues.add(k + aValue); // last case, or if a is 0
```